# How to double everything in a Prolog list (including sublists)

Tags: prolog, sublist

I have a Prolog function that must take in a list (which may include sublists) and return a list that has everything doubled.

For example,

```
?- doubleAll([1,2,[3,4],5,[6,7,[8],9],10), L).

L = [2,4,[6,8],10,[12,14,[16],18],20).
```

I was able to double everything when there were no sublists in the list, but when sublists are included I'm having some problems. Here is my code so far:

%L2 is the result of doubling everything in L1.

```
doubleEverything([],[]).
doubleEverything([H|T], [H2|T2]) :-
   atomic(H), H2 is H*2, doubleEverything(T,T2).
doubleEverything([H|T], [H2|T2]) :-
   not(atomic(H)), H2 is H*2, doubleEverything(T,T2), doubleEverything(H,T2).
```

Does anyone see how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: If Head is a list, you can call doubleEverything recursively on it to double everything it contains, can't you?

Comment: @Haile : I guess so?  It sounds like you should be able to. Would it look like this: doubleEverything(H,H2)? I understand what needs to be done logically, but following all the recursive sections is what trips me up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
double( [] , [] ) .            % doubling the empty list is...the empty list.
double( [X|Xs] , [XX|XXs] ) :- % if the head of the list is a list,
  is_list(X) ,                 % we double it, then double the tail.
  ! ,
  double(X,XX) ,
  double(Xs,XXs)
  .
double( [X|Xs] , [XX XXs] ) :- % doubling anything else is easy.
  XX is X*2 ,
  double(Xs,XXs)
  .

is_list( X     ) :- var(X) , ! , fail .
is_list( []    ) .
is_list( [_|_] ) .
```

Answer (score 1):

`not(atomic(H)), H2 is H*2,` doesn't make sense.
Since atomic(H) (should be number(H), really) is already handled, simply recurse:

```
doubleEverything([H|T], [H2|T2]) :-
   doubleEverything(H,H2), doubleEverything(T,T2).
```

Keep it simple, but remember to test what will happen if neither a number or a list is input...